# Why the font DejaVu Sans Mono looks different in (G)Vim and Emacs?

Tags: vim, emacs, fonts

I think the line-spacing is different in both editors.

How can I set the font in Vim to look like in Emacs?

**Emacs**

[image]

**.emacs:**

```
== Default Font ====

;; Font family
(set-default-font "DejaVu Sans Mono")

;; Font size 
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 100)
```

**Vim**

[image]

**.vimrc:**

```
" set default font
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ 10
```

Comment: Shouldn't `set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ 10` be instead `set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono:h10`?

Comment: @cefstat I'm on Ubuntu, I think set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono:h10 is for Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

emacs GUI is using libxft to render fonts, while GVim uses gtk/pango. There could be difference with font hinting.